# ASP.NET Web API converting JSON into a Object instance skips Data Annotations for int value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, modelstate

Problem with Json binding into Object. int values aren't validated via an appropriate attribute.
I want to validate TimeOut value.
Simplied Class:

```
public class SimpleObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Command { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TimeOut { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Simple controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SimpleObject request)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.Where(x => x.Errors.Count > 1);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Using fiddler I'm sending this Json

```
{"type":"Foo"}
```

The Fun begins now as ModelState.Keys at controller shows the following:

```
Count = 2
    [0]: "Type"
    [1]: "Command"
```

Where is ModelState validation key for TimeOut? If I try to send Type and Command and omit the TimeOut it even sets ModelState as valid.
Tried with mvc 3 and mvc 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that validations works after serialization. The json is deserialized to the object, and the TimeOut is 0. But the required attribute only checks for null, so TimeOut is fine.

You can either make TimeOut Nullable:

```
public int? Timeout { get; set; }
```

or use the RangeAttribute:

```
[Range(1, 10000)]
public int Timeout { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Timeout is not null type, and is equal to 0 by default.

Comment: When object SimpleObject was created the Timeout was set to zero (default int value). And during validation you can check that Timeout is set. Change type to "int?" or add Range validator.